# How to use/override the readObject method,so that it is called inside the actionPerformed method?

Tags: java, serialization, inputstream

Is there any way to call the overridden readObject method inside the actionPerformed?As it cannot be called explicitly,is there any way of doing this?here is what i am trying to do:-

```
 class ContinueActionListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("Dpuzzle.sre");
            ObjectInputStream fileInObject = new ObjectInputStream(input);
            //GridGame game = (GridGame)(fileInObject.readObject());  i dont want to call readObject but instead i want to override it.
            //fileInObject.close();
            //StageSelect stages = new StageSelect();
            //stages.setTheGame(game);
            //stages.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            //no game to continue or file lost.
            System.out.println("hell");
        }
    }


}
```

So how can i override the `readObject` method so that it is called from inside the `actionPerformed` method?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you show us some example code to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: @andersschuller updated please check

Answer (score 1):

You can override it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{      
    ObjectInputStream fileInObject = new ObjectInputStream(){
        @Override
        protected Object readObjectOverride() throws IOException,
                ClassNotFoundException {
            System.out.println("HELLO");

            return null;
        }
    };      
    fileInObject.readObject();
}
```

Output: HELLO

You cannot override readObject directly its a final method.

Comment: +1 good catch on the `final` signature

Comment: but i have seen example of overriding it.

Comment: Can you post the code for your overriding example?

Comment: i am talking about void readObject(ObjectInputStream).

Comment: @Rouftantical That's a private final method inside the object being deserialized, not an override of anything. It will be called automatically when you call ObjectInputStream.readObject(), which you aren't doing at present.